# ST_Intersection of overlaping lines segments returns Point geometry instead LineString

Tags: postgis, intersection

In the table there are several overlapping LineString objects. I would like to extract the overlapped segments, but ST_Intersection function returns Point geometry instead of LineString geometry. When i use ST_Difference between the same pair of geometry it returns LineString geometry. I have no idea why...

```
"LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632103.021656775 494445.107106351)"
"LINESTRING(632103.021656775 494445.107106351,632105.975288636 494433.498307163)"
"LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632097.05179906 494468.570720864)"
"LINESTRING(632097.05179906 494468.570720864,632105.975288636 494433.498307163)"
"LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632100.343463809 494455.633335008)"
"LINESTRING(632100.343463809 494455.633335008,632105.975288636 494433.498307163)"
```

Comment: The accepted answer is good, but you could also try to make  small buffer around one of your linestring sets using st_buffer().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for you seeing point geometries is that the linestrings aren't "perfectly" on top of each other. If you snap on to each other, you will see that the intersection is indeed a linestring.

This query will return a point intersection

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
    ST_Intersection(
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632103.021656775 494445.107106351)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632097.05179906 494468.570720864)')
    )
);
```

Whereas this query using `ST_Snap` will return what you would expect.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
    ST_Intersection(
        ST_Snap(
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632103.021656775 494445.107106351)'),
            ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632097.05179906 494468.570720864)'),
            0.001
        ),
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632097.05179906 494468.570720864)')
    )
);
```

This is the [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=580f87f7375b4afb0503a0245c9b83c8).

Comment: Thanks for response. Your tip improved my case, but in case of some linestring pair i still receive point geometry... `LINESTRING(632097.05179906 494468.570720864,632105.975288636 494433.498307163) LINESTRING(632089.750744759 494497.266400368,632100.343463809 494455.633335008)`

Comment: No worries @AdamS - I believe the reasons for this is because the vertices are too far apart from each other which makes it trickier. Check out the last fiddle I added https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=14557aaf28f4116194fa9123ad025904